# com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads | ERROR

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, admob, google-play-services

After update it to version 21.0.0, I get an error msg
(The Val cannot reassign).

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.0.0'

```
    AndroidView(
    factory = {
        AdView(it).apply {
            adSize = AdSize.FULL_BANNER
            adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-....62"
            loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        }

    },
)
```

Comment: Do you initialize  MobileAds.initializer ?

Comment: @MuhammadBasitJamilAbbasi Yes, In the MainActivity()

Comment: MobileAds.initialize(this) {}

Comment: check adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-....62" add a test adunitid  donot add like this "ca-app-pub-....62"

Comment: I know that, But I just post it here like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `adSize` is now marked private in `21.0.0`.
Use the standard setter method instead - `setAdSize(yourAdSize)`